# What is -u used for in the code "pip install numpy -u"

Tags: python, terminal, pip, anaconda

I've searched a lot on the internet but still do not understand what the above line of code does.
The question is in the title.
Please Explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may depend on the version of `pip` you're using.  For me, there is no `-u` option:

```
$ pip --version
pip 22.1.2

$ pip install numpy -u

Usage:
  pip3 install [options]  [package-index-options] ...
  pip3 install [options] -r  [package-index-options] ...
  pip3 install [options] [-e]  ...
  pip3 install [options] [-e]  ...
  pip3 install [options]  ...

no such option: -u
```

It's possible you mean `-U` which is short for `--upgrade`.

```
$ pip install --help
...
Install Options:
  ...
  -U, --upgrade               Upgrade all specified packages to the newest
                              available version. The handling of dependencies
  ...
...

$ pip install numpy==1.22.0
Collecting numpy==1.22.0
  Using cached numpy-1.22.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (14.7 MB)
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.22.0

pdunn@CHA-SHITEST11 /c/git/personal/python/pygame/game (master)
$ pip install -U numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy ... (1.22.0)
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.23.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (14.6 MB)
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Attempting uninstall: numpy
    Found existing installation: numpy 1.22.0
    Uninstalling numpy-1.22.0:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.22.0
Successfully installed numpy-1.23.1
```

Answer (score 4):

-U is the shortend vervion of --upgrade.

Upgrade all specified packages to the newest available version. The handling of dependencies depends on the upgrade-strategy used.

Answer (score 1):

-U or --upgrade

Upgrades all specified packages to the newest available version.

pip install prefers to leave the installed version as-is unless --upgrade is specified.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

That command means to install the package "numpy"  and then upgrade numpy and related packages to the latest version if there's the need. You can see the information on [pip's document](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install).

Answer (score 0):

ReadThe Docs: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/getting-started/#upgrade-a-package

The parameter `-u` is just the short form of `--upgrade`